# load buttons via ajax and then after clicking loaded buttons,load further contents for the relevant button

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to load some content in form of  **buttons** via ajax and then after clicking those **loaded** buttons I want to be able to load further contents for each button relevantly.

is this possible ?

Here is what I have till now !

Calling Function by **onclick**.

```
<button onclick="findWeek(<?php echo $row['week']; ?>)"></button>
```

This will be the div which will have the loaded content:

```
 <div id="stats">

 </div>
```

**Function**

```
 function findWeek(ide)     
             {              

                var xhr =  new XMLHttpRequest();



                xhr.open("GET" ,"start.php?ide="+ide,true);

                xhr.send(null);


                xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
                    if( (xhr.readyState == '4') && ( xhr.status == '200') )
                    {

                        document.getElementById("stats").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
                    }


                };

            }
```

The **loaded** content is from the file **start.php**.

Here is the code of `start.php`, this will be loaded and then will be feed to the **div** with id `#stats`.

When these buttons are loaded I want to be able to click on these buttons and load further contents that is related with each button.

**start.php**

```
if($run = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT `day` from `foodd_schedule` WHERE `week` = '$week' group by day")){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)){

            ?>

 <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="findday()"><?php echo $row['day']; ?></button>
```

**findday Function** inside `start.php` file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function findday(){
    alert("I'm called");
}
```

The `findday()` function is not even called and the console shows the error of `findday()` is not defined.

How to solve this problem.
Thanks.

Comment: start.php how do you get ide value? Also, for complex operations, try to test each function before adding more?

Comment: I've send `ide` when I called the fucntion `findweek()`, you see !, obviously I've that , that's why I've send them as an argument.